# How to display notifications on windows using flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, notifications

I want to show notifications on windows using Flutter. But I'm unable to do so.

I've tried packages like [deskkop_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/desktop_notifications) and [flutter_local_notifications](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications). But none seems to work. I've tried Cloud Firestore too but it doesn't support windows.

Also, I've read online that it doesn't matter which platform you use, the project will work fine. But that doesn't seem true for me.

[Reference](https://www.reddit.com/r/Flutter/comments/g1vlzp/is_it_possible_to_create_desktop_notifications/)

Is there any way to do so? If not, then is there any other way to capture the user's attention? (when the app is running)

Something like this -

[image: Something like this]
(Source - Google)

Extra - I am not talking of any specific kind of notification (like push notification), any type of notification will do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently push notifications on Windows desktop don‘t seem to be possible. Your reference is about flutter push notification on the web. For windows desktop there currently aren’t any packages on pub dev. If Notification is a key feature of your App. You could make a WebApp first, and wait for a package which supports Windows desktop notifications…

Edit: There is a [flutter_local_notifications package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_local_notifications) which supports local notifications on Android, iOS, MacOS and Linux.

Answer (score 1):

There are packages available on pub that support desktop notifications.
try [M_toast package](https://pub.dev/packages/m_toast)